# Triple Less Than Sign in Bash

Tags: bash

While reading other people's bash code, I found a triple less than sign.

What does `<<<` mean in Bash?

Comment: Type `info bash` or read the [bash manual here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), and search for "<<<". You should develop the habit of Reading The Fine Manual before posting a question.

Comment: It's ok to use Google: http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html

Comment: @hakre: 1. Follow the link in my previous comment. 2. Find out how to install `info` on your system. (One possible difficulty: Debian does not install the bash info manual by default. This does not apply to Debian derivatives like Ubuntu.)

Comment: I think this has been downvoted because it was linked from [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208756/should-we-reopen-a-question-if-it-is-closed-with-a-wrong-reason). Sorry @user2675805.

Comment: As always, links to the ABS should be taken with a grain of salt. The reference manual is unfortunately quite terse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that the standard input of the command is set to a given string.

For example

```
command <<< "String"
```

is equivalent to

```
echo "String" | command
```

Comment: what's the difference between "<<<" and "<"? Does "<<<" work on string and "<" work on file?

Comment: @user2675805 Exactly.

Comment: Please note that this syntax is [not in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07).

Answer (score 5):

It's a here string:

http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings

It's actually an enhanced Here Document:

```
cat <<EOF
data
here
EOF
```

Equivalent to:

```
cat <<< "data
here"
```

Please read more info through `man bash`.